# On Windows, Import CSV file into python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a CSV file into python using the following code.

### Code

```py
    from csv import reader
    path = "C:\\Users\Hp Folio 9480m\Desktop"
    opened_file = open (path,newline='')
    read_file = reader (opened_file)
    print(read_file)

    from csv import reader
    opened_file = open ('C:\\Users\Hp Folio 9480m\Desktop.csv')
    read_file = reader (opened_file)
    print(read_file)
```

However, This returns me the following error:

### Error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hp Folio 9480m/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/victor.py/op.py", line 3, in <module>
opened_file = open (path,newline='')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Hp Folio 9480m\\Desktop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hp Folio 9480m/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/victor.py/op.py", line 2, in <module>
opened_file = open ('C:\\Users\Hp Folio 9480m\Desktop.csv')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Hp Folio 9480m\\Desktop.csv'
```

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with your file path btw ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pandas lib for this

1 >  pip install pandas

run this command on your terminal / cmd to install pandas lib on your computer

then

```
import pandas as pd




data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

## import your CSV file

```
with open("your file name path", "r") as file:
```